# Mp3 файл после 15 разовое проигрывание не проигрываетсия

Tags: android, mediaplayer

Исползовал классы **mediaplayer**
 для проигрование mp3 файлов но он работет только 15 раз после mp3 файли перестанет проигроватсия.

Вот мой класс для проигрование mp3 файлов:

```
public class Speech{
private Context cont;
private SoundPool sp;
private int soundId = 0;
int status = 0;
public Speech(Context ct) {
    this.cont = ct;
} 

public void speechMedia(String id) {
    try {
        int idres = cont.getResources().getIdentifier(id, "raw", cont.getPackageName());
        player = MediaPlayer.create(cont, idres);
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
        }
        player.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Тестировал на разные телефоны но результат одинаковый

Comment: покажите код и сформулируйте вопрос?

Comment: В 4.4.2 все норм работает а в 7.0 проигровает 15 файлов после проста не проигровет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите логи при новом воспроизведении. Возможно, у вас заканчивается память после 15 раза и медиа плеер не может запуститься. Не забывайте вызывать метод `release()` у экземпляра MediaPlayer, чтобы освободить ресурсы.

Comment: В setoncompletionListner осбоводил ресурси. release